# How to make an element with a fixed width but relative height in scroll box

Tags: css

I have a `<pre>` with a `<code>` block inside, of which can expand to some `max-height` after which a scollbar appears. I wish to add a `:before` to this, which will have the same length as the content inside the `<code>` block, but is only ever some fixed number of pixels wide. For context, I'm adding line numbers before lines in a `<code>` block in a subreddit I moderate (so I can only use CSS), abusing the `content:` property and a list of numbers. Here is a stripped down version of what I am using:

```css
pre {
    max-height: 50px;
 border:1px solid #000000;
 z-index:1;
 position:relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
pre code{
 padding:0px 11px 0px 11px!important;
 margin-left:30px;
 display:block;
}

pre code:before{
 height: 100%;
 color:#FFF;
 position: absolute;
 left:-5px;
 width:30px;
 white-space:pre-wrap;
 direction:rtl;
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:2;
 background:#369;
 left:0px;
 padding-right:5px;
 content:"1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10"
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>Line one
Line two
Line three
Line four
Line five
Line six
Line seven
</code>
</pre>
```

This works pretty well, except for the fact that the `:before` which appears to the left of the code block don't extend all the way down when the length of the `<code>` content exceeds the `max-height`, causing it to create a scrollbar. It is only visible as far down as the visible size of the scroll box-  not the `<code>` content itself (scroll down inside the box). I could replace `height: 100%` with `height: auto`, but then the numbers extend well beyond the length of the `<code>` block.

How can I make the `:before` element I am creating to span the entire height of the `<code>` block inside of the scrollbox, with a fixed width (30px), using only CSS? I also can't "hard code" anything to be the same value as the `max-height`, because it temporarily increases while the user is hovering over the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add position relative to `code` instead of `pre`

The `before` of the `code` was `position absolute`, and you had assigned position `relative` to `pre`, whose height was 50px, that is the height of `before` was only 50px.

Hence by making code relative, the height of `before` became equal to the `code`

```
pre code {
  padding: 0px 11px 0px 40px!important;
  /*margin-left: 30px;*/
  display: block;
  position:relative;
}
```

```css
pre {
  max-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  z-index: 1;
  /*position: relative;*/
  overflow: auto;
}

pre code {
  padding: 0px 11px 0px 40px!important;
  /*margin-left: 30px;*/
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

pre code:before {
  height: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  width: 30px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #369;
  left: 0px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  content: "1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10"
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>Line one
Line two
Line three
Line four
Line five
Line six
Line seven
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: It feels like this has to be the one thing I didn't try. It does mess up the alignment a bit on the actual site, but that's something I'll be able to handle. Thank you-  this solved the issue.